# Windows: Log disk useage of a single file/folder

Tags: windows, hard-drive, monitoring

Is there a utility built into `Windows` that will allow me to monitor the `disk usage` of a single file/folder?

If nothing is built-in, is there a tool I can install to achieve this?

For `CPU usage` of a process, I can use the built-in `Performance Monitor` with a `Data Collector Set`. This doesn't seem to work if I'd like to monitor `disk usage` of a single file/folder though.

Comment: Did you already consider installing a Linux app on your Windows computer? This might make it possible to use `du .` UNIX command.

Comment: @Dominique thank you for the suggestion. That didn't cross my mind. I can install Disk Usage (du) from Windows Sysinternals and use the Task Scheduler to run it when I require. If you submit your response as an Answer I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you already consider installing a Linux app on your Windows computer? This might make it possible to use `du .` UNIX command.